When I use global provides in Vitest, why does injection produce typescript errors
I'm converting from Jest to Vitest and I need to provide global variables to correlate things like user id during testing.
setupTests.ts
import type { GlobalSetupContext } from 'vitest/node';

export default function setup({ provide }: GlobalSetupContext) {
  const now = Date.now();

  // this works, but typescript errors
  provide('uid', `test-user-${now}`);
}

declare module 'vitest' {
  export interface ProvidedContext {
    uid: string;
  }
}

BaseModel.test.ts
...
// this works, but typescript errors
const uid = inject('uid');
...

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "lib",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "types": [
    "vitest/globals",
    "./setupTests.ts"
  ]
}

Typescript isn't picking up the uid string as a valid type, instead throwing an error saying
Argument of type string is not assignable to parameter of type never
